# Sending ajax call to php server returns empty error

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following ajax call in a function, which is called upon a clickevent.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"server.php",
  type:'GET',
  data: {'action':'addEvent'},
  success: function(response)
  {
    if(response)
    {
    alert("200 ok");                
    }
 },
 error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, ThrownError)
 {
   alert("Error:" + ThrownError);
   $("#output").text("Error: "+ThrownError);
 }
});
```

The php side is as follows.

```
  if(isset($_GET["action"]))
   {
      $action = $_GET["action"];
     if($action == 'addEvent')
     {
          echo("ping");
     }

   }
```

Now it throws an error. But the error message i get is :

Exactly, i get Error:

It is driving me crazy.

Also i put in my document.ready, to let it act as some sort of ping, and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Dev that was exactly my problem, if i had an error this question would not be here

Comment: What is exact response you receive? You can take a look at it in developer tool (F12, you may need to install FireBug in FF), network tab or something similar

Comment: I get no response, absolutely nothing. But it does give a response when i put in document.ready()

Comment: Click event on what? Link, form button, something else?

Comment: Can you post whole click event handler?

Comment: It is a click event handler, it calls the function this ajax piece of code is in, but it calls perfectly, i put an alert just above the $ajax and it went off fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh9Za/). I'm getting there same error you have.

Why that is happening there: link is clicked and ajax request is sent. But default action is not stopped and browser navigates to url specified in `href` and stops any JS execution. AJAX call is stopped too.

In order to prevent that, you should do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) { 
    $.ajax({
      url:"server.php",
      type:'GET',
      data: {'action':'addEvent'},
      success: function(response) {
        if(response) {
           alert("200 ok");                
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, ThrownError) {
         alert("Error:" + ThrownError);
         $("#output").text("Error: "+ThrownError);
      }
   }); 
   e.preventDefault();//this will not allow browser to move to a different URL
   return false; //alternative to e.preventDefault(). 
});​
```

Possibly you have similar problem, but it is hard to notice because your element is causing simple page reload, browser navigates to the same page.

Comment: This helped. I just got success. This just worked. O my god. So epic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The function definition for error is the following:

```
error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

further, try to get more info by defining the following

`statusCode`

A map of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be called when the response has the corresponding code. For example, the following will alert when the response status is a 404:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert('page not found');
    }
  }
});
```

If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error, they take the same parameters as the error callback.

`success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`

so now, you have two more functions defined(success + http code). so if the request fails, it would execute code in error, if it successful it will execute `success`. In both case, you will get the http response code. check if the code is 200, then everything went well. 404 - the script url is wrong. 500 - there is a server error & so on.

Comment: when i print jqXHR.status i get 0. But i am not sure that this is the actual statusCode, is there a way i can output the statusCode?